gitbub actions shown as success but test report failied
i am running a github test with maven. The test report is failing but the github summery is shown as success.
The result of the run maven in gthub actions shows one error:
Error:  Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
how can i "tell" that the github job should fail if the test report has an Error or Failure?
my mvn command in github workflow file:
 - name: Run tests with maven
      if: success()
      run: mvn -Dchromedriver_exe_path=${{ env.chromedriver_exe_path }} -Dbrowser=${{ env.browser }} -Denvironment=${{ env.environment }} -Dset_browser_dimensions=${{ env.use_monitor_size }} -Dheadless=true "-Dcucumber.filter.tags=${{ env.tags }}" -D clean verify 
      env:
        DISPLAY: ":2"


Due to i am running several test and i want that all tests are running even if one is failing i cannot set false in my pom.xml. so this is not the solution for me: github actions maven step failing but shown as success
 <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
        <configuration>
          <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

how can i "tell" that the github job should fail if the test report has an Error or Failure?
